# Cylindrical shell method rotation about a vertical line $x = 3$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The boundaries are $y = x^3$, $y = 8$, and $x = 0$ about $x = 3$

I've tried $\mathrm{radius} = 3 - x$ and $\mathrm{height} = x^3$ with limit $b = 2$ and $a = 0$.

Then I've tried it with $b = 8$ and $a = 0$.

Then I've tried $x^{1/3}$ as height. I've tried changing the radius to $x$. I've tried $b = 3$ and $a = 0$, $b = 3$ and $a = 2$, I've tried EVERYTHING. I drew the graph, I tried every combination, and nothing.

Comment: It's not even clear what you're after. Are you trying to find the volume of the surface of revolution you described?

Comment: Your second sentence is almost correct: The height should be $8 - x^3$ though, instead of $x^3$. Do you see why?

Comment: Oh, it's like the cylindrical method about x-axis. Then I'm guessing the limits are b = 2 and a = 0? I'll try that out now.

Comment: Yea, it worked. All these crazy rules... SIGH. Thanks though.